# Dealing with special characters like (ö, Ä, é, ß) in iOS

Tags: nsstring, nsstringencoding

I am fetching data from URL, and this data contains special characters, such as in the name `Désirée`.

I want to display this in my TableView cell, but when I display it, it looks like this: `DÃ¶sirÃ¶e`.

How do I make it display correctly?

**Fetch data**

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL] encoding: NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
dictShow = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
arr=[dictShow copy];
```

**Display Data in TableView**

```
cell.textLabel.text = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: How are you fetching your data? You need to interpret it using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` rather than an old ISO encoding.

Comment: You have an encoding problem somewhere. It could be server side or client-side. Post the code where you download the data.

Comment: I am using json for fetching the data and storing it in a Dictionary..

Comment: Have you inserted that code..?
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

Comment: NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy is not an encoding. It is a conversion option, and the value happens to be the same as NSASCIIStringEncoding. Use NSUTF8StringEncoding instead as Cyrille already suggested.

Comment: Good suggestion it is working..i am able to display it in tableview but i am unable to fetch data when i pass `Désirée abcd` to my new URL data is there but i am unable to fetch it.. i have used same code for fetching the data which i wrote above.

Comment: @Krunal: Why did you edit your question long after the answer has been accepted? That will it make impossible for future readers to understand the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use `NSUTF8StringEncoding instead` of `NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy` like....

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

Comment: Yes, `NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy` is not actually a valid encoding type. It's an option to control how characters should be handled when *en*coding a string